# Clojure: O(1) function to check if sequence has exactly 1 element

Tags: performance, clojure, functional-programming, predicate

Is there a fast way to check if a sequence has exactly 1 element in Clojure? Note that a sequence may contain nils.

If I'm reading the [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ASeq.java#L114) correctly, calling `count` on a sequence takes O(n) time.

Alternate solution:

```
(and
  (not (empty? a-seq))
  (empty? (rest a-seq)))
```

[Docs](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/empty?) say that calling `empty?` on collection `coll` is the same as calling `(not (seq coll))`, but they don't specify its efficiency or what happens when you call `empty?` on a sequence. I tried to search the github repository for how `empty?` was implemented, but it was ignoring the question mark in searches and there was a ton of hits on "empty". I would imagine `empty?` and `rest` are O(1), but then again, `count` wasn't...

Comment: (did not bother checking sources, so take it with grain of salt) I would be highly surprised that the `empty?` implementation is not constant time.

Comment: Well, I was highly surprised that `count` was not constant time :)

Comment: how can you tell the length of a sequence without iterating it?

Comment: Sequences can be lazy and infinite, so the interface can't support constant-time counting.

Comment: A sequence can be constructed in run time during its consumption: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-seq

Comment: Note that `count` is O(1) on certain collections. The `counted?` function tells you if this is the case for a specific collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

```
user=> (empty? (cycle [1]))
false
```

(the fact that the function terminates), I assume `empty?` evaluates in constant time, namely, `(seq coll)` initialises a sequence in constant time.

```
user=> (source empty?)
(defn empty?
  "Returns true if coll has no items - same as (not (seq coll)).
  Please use the idiom (seq x) rather than (not (empty? x))"
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [coll] (not (seq coll)))
nil
```

Your code does the thing rather well. Maybe I'd say:

```
user=> (defn single-elem? [s]
  #_=>   (and
  #_=>     (seq s)
  #_=>     (empty? (rest s))))
#'user/single-elem?

user=> (single-elem? [1])
true
user=> (single-elem? [1 2])
false
user=> (single-elem? [])
nil
user=> (single-elem? {:foo :bar})
true
user=> (single-elem? {:foo :bar :fez 42})
false
```

Answer (score 3):

The following function was added in 1.9 (which is still alpha as of now):

```
(defn bounded-count
  "If coll is counted? returns its count, else will count at most the first n
  elements of coll using its seq"
  {:added "1.9"}
  [n coll]
  (if (counted? coll)
    (count coll)
    (loop [i 0 s (seq coll)]
      (if (and s (< i n))
        (recur (inc i) (next s))
        i))))
```

So I guess a `(bounded-count 2 coll)` should give you a constant time count for what you need.

Comment: This is begging the question. You are assuming that `next` is constant time. See [@amalloy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38391165/1562315).

Comment: It is constant time.

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, take [clojure/data.priority-map](https://crossclj.info/doc/org.clojure/data.priority-map/latest/index.html). This has logarithmic `pop`, hence logarithmic `next`. Not even `peek` is constant time. See [these docs](https://crossclj.info/ns/org.clojure/data.priority-map/0.0.7/clojure.data.priority-map.html).

Comment: True indeed! Though, these (all?) data structures are counted so `bounded-count` is still constant time. Is there a (common) data structure that is not counted and `next` is non-constant?

Answer (score 3):

When sequences can be lazy, you can't really talk about "constant time", because any amount of work may have been deferred in the construction of the input sequence. For example, consider this sequence:

```
(filter even? (filter odd? (range)))
```

Calling `seq` on this sequence will never return a result of any kind ,unless you wait long enough to exceed `Long/MAX_VALUE`.

However, in general functions do exactly the minimum amount of work they need to do. So `seq` does just enough work to determine what the first element of the collection is, if any, and `next` does just enough work to determine what the first and second elements are, if any.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes:

---

> Docs say that calling `empty?` on a collection is the same as calling
>   `(not (seq coll))`, but they don't specify its efficiency or what happens
>   when you call `empty?` on a sequence.

`empty?` works on sequences, whether based on a collection or not. It is *defined* as the complement of `seq`:

```
(defn empty? [coll]
  (not (seq coll)))
```

---

I'd rewrite your function as

```
(defn one-element? [coll]
  (and (seq coll)
       (empty? (rest coll))))
```

or

```
(defn one-element [coll]
  (and (seq coll)
       (not (next coll))))
```

These are of the same order of speed as `seq` and `rest`/`next` are.